# Is it possible to assign a TFS Review Request to nobody?

Tags: tfs

The built-in TFS review workflow seems oriented around sending reviews directly to one or more people and does not allow you to leave the assignment box blank. This presents a problem, because if I try to pick one person, I need to be checking the work items to make sure that person has time to do the review, or that they do not have too many reviews already. If I send it to all of the reviewers, they each get their own Work Item and could potentially review the same code multiple times. That's not necessarily a bad thing, but not the desired outcome here. It also leads to a proliferation of Work Items that can get tricky to query down to a meaningful dataset.

We have a number of developers who are authorized to perform code reviews. We'd like to have requests go into an unassigned pool where reviewers can reach in and grab a review to complete. This would allow them to take work as they have time, and perhaps self-select based on their knowledge of the related domain. Perhaps this would come with a single Work Item that could be used to track the review status.

Is this possible with TFS 2015 Update 2? At the very least, the question in the title would help with having too many Work Items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, **there is no such settings in VS or TFS2015**. Before you check in your code, you can use Visual Studio to **ask** someone else from your team to review it. Your request will show up in his team explorer, in the *'my work'* page.

In my opinion, the code review is that you need to ask someone to finish it, not  you choice to assign a work in a pool and somebody jump into then pick up the work.

As for you choose to send the review request to one person or a group. How to make sure they have enough time and based on their knowledge of the related domain. This is the related workflow in your own team. It's not hard to determine which one take responsible for each module.

The concern of 'review the same code multiple times' is not necessary, your team can define a minimum number of reviewers need to finish the review before close it. And also people can directly see the status of other reviewers  to determine whether accept or decline the review.

[image]

However,the problem of too many work items. There are no good solutions. Only one I'm afraid is to reduce the sending persons.

Moreover, if you think it's a good suggestion and really need this feature, you can ask a  feature request in [User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services). PM and TFS administrator will kindly review it.